# sql get a tree from hierarchical tables

Tags: sql

if you have a hierarchy of tables, each item in a table containing a reference to the id of its parent in the parent table, is there a way to obtain that tree from a single (few) sql query as a tree?

- specy (id, name, genus)
- genus (id, name, family)
- family (id, name)

Something looking like:

```
SELECT *
FROM specy
JOIN genus ON genus.id=specy.genus
JOIN family ON genus.family=family.id
```

But even if that was correct syntactically, would it not return a dataset with a family field for each genus of this family, and both a family and a genus field for each specy of that genus?

Can SQL return a hierarchical tree directly (easily), or only a dataset which I must then process in another language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, SQL can return hierarchical data using [common table expressions (CTEs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL), but not all databases support CTEs. The syntax is:

```
WITH [RECURSIVE] with_query [, ...]
SELECT...
```

Example:

```
WITH RECURSIVE table1 (n, fact) AS 
(SELECT col1+1, col1*col2 FROM table1)
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

Comment: MariaDB -- the MySQL clone -- 10.2+ can do CTEs.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to see the redundant information you can order the results by family and genus, then use user variables to replace duplicates from the previous row with blanks. You'll then only see the family and genus names when they change.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN f.id = @prev_family THEN '' ELSE f.name END AS family,
       CASE WHEN g.id = @prev_genus THEN '' ELSE g.name END AS genus,
       s.name AS species
FROM specy AS s
JOIN genus AS g ON s.genus = g.id
JOIN family AS f ON g.family = f.id
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @prev_family := 0, @prev_genus := 0) AS vars
ORDER BY f.id, g.id, s.id
```